# QPixmap vacio al cargarlo desde una imagen

Tags: c++, windows, qt

Tengo una aplicación que carga en un QPixmap una imagen, que según lo requiera el usuario, la imagen varía. No tienen todas la imágenes el mismo formato, ni el mismo tamaño, algunas en vertical y otras en horizontal. Estoy utilizando Qt5.14.2, con MinGW 7.3.0 32-bits y  Qt Creator 4.11.1. en W10. En un equipo con W8.1 y la misma versión de Qt, MinGW y QtCreator ha estado funcionando bien.

La primera imagen se carga perfectamente, pero si la cambio, ya retorna el QPixmap vacío.

He hecho distintas pruebas para poder cargar la imagen, redimensionando el QPixmap (con unas dimensiones fijas y con las de la imagen), sacar el QImage a un fichero y cargarlo desde el fichero indicando el formato PNG, etc.  He podido comprobar que las imágenes se generan correctamente, para descartar que sería un problema al convertir el data al QImage. ¿Alguna idea de qué puede estar pasando? No puedo poner el código por que es una aplicación bastante extensa, así que lo reduzco a donde se encuentra el problema

En My_class.h:

`QPixmap pixmap;`

En My_class.cpp:

```
int w=num_celdas_imagen_x*128;
int h=num_celdas_imagen_y*128;
unsigned char *data =(unsigned char *)malloc(w*h*3);

// se rellena el data

QImage img = QImage((unsigned char *)data,w,h,QImage::Format_RGB888);

// En este punto he podido comprobar que la imagen se genera correctamente

this->pixmap = QPixmap::fromImage(img); 

// En este punto el QPixmap ya está vacío (excepto con la primera imagen, que la carga bien)
```

Gracias